# Celery is not working on my Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, celery, amqp

What on earth am I doing wrong?

I have recently found an awesome django template called [django-skel](https://github.com/rdegges/django-skel).  I started a project with it because it made it very easy to use heroku with django.  It was all going great until I tried to get celery working.  No matter what I tried I couldn't get my tasks to run.  So I started a new bare bones app just to see if I could get it working without any of my other craziness preventing things.

This is my [bare-bones app.](https://github.com/cswenor/herokutest) I have this up and running on heroku.  Django admin is working, I have my databases sync'd up and migrated.  I am using CloudAMQP Little Lemur for my RabbitMQ.  I see the requests queued up in the RabbitMQ interface, nothing happens. How I queue up the tasks is manually run in the shell:

```
from herokutest.apps.otgcelery.tasks import add
result = add.delay(2,2)
```

I make sure that I have all 3 dynos running, and still nothing.

Also I have it working locally.

I am sure there are tons of questions, and I'm willing to give them.  Just please ask.

Comment: Do you have a scheduler dyno running? (You shouldn't need a worker dyno if you're processing a small amount of tasks.)

Comment: Also: can you run the following: `heroku ps:restart; heroku logs --tail --source app` and look for any errors when your worker is starting up?

Comment: I am running the scheduler dyno I kicked all three on because just the one wasn't working.  I'll grab the logs for you here in a second.  Thanks.

Comment: Alright I think we are getting somewhere @rdegges: https://gist.github.com/cswenor/5429349

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out the first issue.  I was importing herokutest.apps.otgcelery.tasks rather than just apps.otgcelery.tasks.  Once I did that the first task goes through fine.  If I run it again the second one doesn't go through.  This is the log: https://gist.github.com/cswenor/5429545

Comment: It seems to me like celery isn't dropping the connection and then we hit our limit with AMQP?

Comment: Based on your second gist, it looks like your cloudamqp instance might be having problems? Can you run your task now at all? Does it work sometimes then die? Or is it just not working at all? You may want to message the cloudamqp guys about this. Very, very odd :o

Comment: It runs the first time, but then if I run it again it never completes.  I'll reach out to them.

Comment: I'm currently working with CloudAMQP to see if there is an issue on their side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for everyones help.
There were a couple things that I ended up doing wrong.  First thing was that I was importing the task incorrectly.  All I had to do was:

```
from apps.otgcelery.tasks import add
result = add.delay(2,2)
```

Celery is very picky with how you import your tasks.  The second issue is that CloudAMQP Free addon does not work out of the box with django-skel.  They limit your number of connections to three, and how each thread kicks on it uses those connections up incredibly fast and your tasks just start not connecting.  So I fixed this in a couple different ways.  I tried another BigWigs RabbitMQ, and it worked great.  However, because they were still in Beta I decided to try out Redis.  That also worked great, and my tasks are firing off as fast as I can call them.

Once again thank you everyone for your help.